# How do I convert a UUID from string format to binary format in Lua?

Tags: lua, uuid, pack

In Lua, how do I get most significant bit and least significant bit of a UUID(150b28fc-3f3f-4c74-83e5-ab6a626e0cb1)? I'd like to convert it to binary format using string.pack(">L>L",msb,lsb).

Comment: Do you have a specific example of the an input string, the uuid, that you can add to your question?

Comment: @Nifim Yes. updated my question.